AWSSDK.SQS: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Amazon.Util.Internal.ICryptoUtil
In our .net api, when we update to AWSSDK.Core 3.7.400.37 we are seeing the following exception coming from our background service using AWSSDK.SQS with version 3.7.400.35:
System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Amazon.Util.Internal.ICryptoUtil Amazon.Util.CryptoUtilFactory.get_CryptoInstance()

Error occurred during pull messages from the queue. BackgroundServiceName: SQSQueueConsumerBackgroundService","level":"Error","exception":"System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Amazon.Util.Internal.ICryptoUtil Amazon.Util.CryptoUtilFactory.get_CryptoInstance()'.\r\n   at Amazon.SQS.Internal.ValidationResponseHandler.CalculateMD5(Byte[] bytes)\r\n   at Amazon.SQS.Internal.ValidationResponseHandler.ValidateMD5(String message, String messageId, String md5FromService)\r\n   at Amazon.SQS.Internal.ValidationResponseHandler.ValidateMD5(Message message)\r\n   at Amazon.SQS.Internal.ValidationResponseHandler.ValidateReceiveMessage(ReceiveMessageResponse response)\r\n   at Amazon.SQS.Internal.ValidationResponseHandler.PostInvoke(IExecutionContext executionContext)\r\n   at Amazon.SQS.Internal.ValidationResponseHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)\r\n   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)\r\n   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)\r\n   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)\r\n   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Signer.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)\r\n   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.EndpointDiscoveryHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)\r\n   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.EndpointDiscoveryHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)\r\n   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CredentialsRetriever.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)\r\n   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RetryHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)\r\n   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RetryHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)\r\n   at Amazon.XRay.Recorder.Handlers.AwsSdk.Internal.XRayPipelineHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)\r\n   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)\r\n   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)\r\n   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorCallbackHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)\r\n   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.MetricsHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)\r\n   at MyService.SqsClient.Services.BaseQueueBackgroundService.PullQueueMessages()"

I have seen that its occured in a previous issue reported in 2022:
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/issues/1992
Is the same or something different?
